# Run a bash script via another bash script to delete a file is not working properly

Tags: bash, command, prompt

I have a bash script `start.sh` which calls another `run.sh`, which takes me to another prompt where I have to delete a file `file.txt` and then exit out of that prompt.

When I call `run.sh` from inside `start.sh`, I see the prompt and I believe that it deletes the `file.txt` but the inner/new prompt waits for me to exit out of it while the script is running - meaning it needs intervention to proceed. How do I avoid it in bash?

In Python I can use Popen and get it going but not sure about bash.

EDIT: I would rather like to know what command to provide to exit out of the shell (generated from running run.sh") so I can go back to the prompt where "start.sh" was started.

Etan: To answer your question

```
VirtualBox:~/Desktop/ > ./start

company@4d6z74d:~$ ->this is the new shell
company@4d6z74d:~$ logout ---> I did a "Control D here" so the script could continue.
```

Relevant part of start.sh which:

```
/../../../../run.sh (this is the one that takes us to the new $ prompt)

echo "Delete file.txt " 
rm -f abc/def/file.txt
```

Comment: How is `run.sh` prompting for input? Can you show the relevant part of `run.sh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run run.sh in the background using `&`.  In start.sh, you would invoke the script via `/path/run.sh &`.  Now, start.sh will exit without waiting for run.sh to finish (which is running in the background).